# SharePoint Online Management Sell conflicts with Share Point Online Client Component SDK

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

My PC has both Share Point Online Client Component SDK and SharePoint Online Management Shell(16.0.20414.12000) installed. When trying to execute command `Connect-SPOService -Url $SpSiteURL` it gives below error.

> The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet

When trying to import the module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell, it gives below error

> Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PortalLaunch.PortalLaunchRedirectionType'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing,
> Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

I found a few internet resources asking to [uninstall Share Point Online Client Component SDK](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/02/import-module-could-not-load-type-microsoft-sharepoint-administration-designpackagetype-from-assembly.html) to resolve this issue,however this is not a possible solution, since I need both for different scenarios.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when trying to run these scripts on an on-premise SharePoint 2013 machine which has a different set off DLLs in the GAC. I don't want to break my SharePoint 2013 setup by removing the GAC versions …

My solution was to run the scripts on a non SharePoint installed machine.